# Virtual environment is active, but nothing is actually affected in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtual-environment

I'm coding in Python, and I'm trying to create a virtual environment for an educational project I'm about to start. As the tutorials said, I used `venv` for this:

```sh
python3 -m venv tutorial-env
source tutorial-env/bin/activate
```

After this command, I see the environment's name in my terminal

```
(tutorial-env) username@username:~path/to/my/folder$
```

which seems fine.

However, I'm told that after these commands, `which python3` should output the new python3 interpreter that's used in this environment (somewhere in *tutorials-env/*), but it's still */usr/bin/python3*.

Screenshot:

[Screenshot Creating a virtual env and testing it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/usJJ8.png)

I also tried to install packages with pip3 to see if the installed packages are installed in the environment or system-wide, and I realized that pip3 is installing stuff system-wide (I tried switching between environments and install packages inside each of them independently, but it affects all environments).

I also tried using `virtualenv` but the same thing happened.

Am I doing something wrong? My python3's version is 3.8.2, and I'm on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

Comment: Are you trying `which python3` while your virtual environment is active?

Comment: @Suparshva Yes.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of `which python3` with the virtual environment active? Was the virtual enviroment creation successful without error?

Comment: @Suparshva [Screenshot](http://s15.picofile.com/file/8409341434/Screenshot_from_2020_09_26_15_42_41.png). Yes, there were no errors.

Comment: Am I missing something? Your statement "`which python3` is still /usr/bin/python3" does not correspond with what the screenshot says. Also can you do `which pip3` and `which pip`? There's a chance the virtualenv contains only `pip`, and `pip3` is only system-wide.

Comment: thanks, the screenshot looks ok. The output of `which python` is from that of environment directory. `python3` of virtual environment is being used. Do you have any doubts about that?

Comment: You can check by deactivating virtual environment with `deactivate` and verify with `which python` to see path of your user configured python. Both should be different.

Comment: @yedpodtrzitko Strange! It is working properly in my screenshot but in the project's folder, it does not. [screenshot](http://s15.picofile.com/file/8409342142/sefsefsefsfsef.png)

Comment: @Suparshva Yeah, the screenshot is okay (I found out after sending it). But in my project's folder, it doesn't work! [Screenshot](http://s15.picofile.com/file/8409342142/sefsefsefsfsef.png)

Comment: aren't you using something like [autoenv](https://github.com/inishchith/autoenv) which could override the virtualenv in given directory? If not, I'm blaming the special characters in directory name (`:`) and also the length of the path.

Comment: @yedpodtrzitko Wow it WAS because of the ```:```! I changed that folder's name and the problem is solved. Thank you, kind stranger.

Comment: alright, I'm gonna post it as an answer so the question can be marked as solved.

Comment: Can you please [edit] the question to include the full path? The issue is only documented in the comments, which are not necessarily persistent. Just reading the question makes the answer seem like a completely unrelated, random guess.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Good point. Done!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm suspicious about the special characters in directory name `:`, which could be causing troubles.